# Windows 8 notebook display resolution borked after reboot

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, nvidia-quadro

I'm having a weird issue on my Windows 8.1 Pro install at work. Reinstalling is not really an option as I don't have the time for that. I've asked the sysadmin but he doesn't have a clue either.

I have a Dell Precision M4800 notebook which has an Intel HD Graphics 4600 and an NVIDIA Quadro K2100M display adapter. The native resolution of the notebook is 1920x1080. I also have a Dell U2412M secondary monitor attached through a VGA cable, with a native resolution of 1920x1200.

The attached monitor is used as the primary display, while the notebook rests in it's docking station.

Every morning, after I boot my notebook, the resolution on the notebook monitor is completely borked. When I look into the screen resolution properties it's still listed as 1920x1080, but when I open an application the application looks like it's being rendered on 800x600.

In the mean time I developed the habit to change my display resolution back and forth each morning so it's actually 1920x1080, but it's getting annoying to have to do this.

What could cause this? Is there something I can check which could give you more information to help to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am wondering what method the notebook is put to rest in at night? full shutdown or a hybrid style or just sleep? First thing i would do is manueally switch it to a different low res, do a reboot then (saving that info to the registry) , then bring it back up change the res to where it should be, then doing a reboot again (saving that out to the registry).

Comment: I do a full shutdown every night. Another interesting fact is that when I simply reboot, I don't seem to experience the issue. I will try changing the resolution to a lower one this evening and see if that stays persisted correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Or not as I expected. I set my resolution to 1024x768 which resulted in 2 vertical black bars. The application was rendered sharply. When I booted, the black bars were present, and the resolution in the control panel was listed as 1024x768, but the application was rendered blurry and (as far as I can guess) on an even smaller resolution.

Comment: Great, that is another good clue.  some DPI setting or the GPUs software.  Like there is underscan overscan settings in Nvidia and AMD softwares for the HDMi.  So no mater what you do, after a reboot the scaling stuff changes somehow, showing a badly interpolated mess?  You did set it Back to the resolution you desired it to be to begin with?  See if you can find any odd stuff in your GPU software that could effect that.  You could even set "profiles" in most of that GPU software to quickly change things.

Comment: Are there any restrictions placed on this notebook by your workplace (or you) GPO stuff that dissallows certian changes to be made, that are effecting it beyond what anyone intended?  There was a question similar at SU  to what your saying with a bad interpolation on One of 2 monitors and a different interpolation on Metro Vs regular programs.  I am pretty sure it was the windows DPI stuff, but i will try and find those questions. Also GPU software "scaling" options.

Comment: I assume you know  http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements/  and how to turn off the new feature of auto changing that.  and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn528847.aspx which talks about how difficult DPI changes are, and how some programs cope with various changes one way or another.   IF DPI or Scaling (or the crasy overscan) was changing , it may seem like the res itself changed.  A "screenshot" of the desktop using the "print screen" button, then pasting the clipboard into a new paint or photo image, would prove the resolution

Comment: As far as I can tell, I'm the only one at my workplace experiencing those issues, so a GPO thing should not be the problem. I'll check out the links you posted and see if they can make my any wiser.